# JQuery basic tool tips on text boxes and button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, textbox, tooltip

I am trying to add some basic text only tool tips to my application.

how can I do this with JQuery I only need to add some tooltips on some textboxes and maybe buttons.

Sorry I am still new in this area.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery tool tip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) for that

It is very simple .You can use like

```
<script>

 $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting title attribute:

```
<input type="text" title="this is a tooltip"></input>
```